# OS X 10.10.3 and notification center

Tags: objective-c, macos

I developed an app for OS X that should send local notification. I deployed this app for OS X 10.9. The app worked fine until Apple update OS X 10.10.3. I installed the app for a standard (not Administrator) user and when I go under System Preference --> Notification I can't see that the app has permission to send notification.
Here's my code to send a loca notification on OS X:

```
NSUserNotification *notification = [[NSUserNotification alloc]init];
notification.title = title;
notification.informativeText = text;
notification.soundName = NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName;

notification.userInfo = @{@"url": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myurl.com/%@",detailParams]};                    
NSUserNotificationCenter *center = [NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter];
[center setDelegate:self];
[center scheduleNotification:notification];
```

Apple changed something after installation of OS X 10.10.3? If yes what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things ([which I found at a tutorial here](http://blog.mahasoftware.com/post/28968246552/how-to-use-the-10-8-notification-center-api)):

1)

Instead of `scheduleNotification`, try using:

```
[center deliverNotification:notification];
```

2)

Notification Center only displays notifications *if the application is not frontmost.* To always present the notification, you need to set the delegate on the NSUserNotificationCenter as shown above, and implement the NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate as follows:

```
- (BOOL)userNotificationCenter:(NSUserNotificationCenter *)center shouldPresentNotification:(NSUserNotification *)notification
{
    return YES;
}
```